Circular shift a column in a Polars dataframe
How can I get a circular shift of a column in a Polars dataframe?
For example, say I start with this dataframe,
df = pl.DataFrame(dict(a=range(1, 10)))

and I want to add a column b that is a circular shift of column a, where the number of places shifted is 3. Then the expected output is this:
shape: (9, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 8   │
│ 3   ┆ 9   │
│ 4   ┆ 1   │
│ 5   ┆ 2   │
│ 6   ┆ 3   │
│ 7   ┆ 4   │
│ 8   ┆ 5   │
│ 9   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘


I quite like taking by index, where the array of indices is constructed by mapping (x - 3) % len over range(len(df)).
df.with_columns(b=pl.col("a").gather((pl.arange(pl.len()) - 3) % pl.len()))

Explanation:

gather: get multiple elements by index (one per index provided)

pl.arange(pl.len()): expression form equivalent of range(len(df))
... - 3: shift forward by 3
... % pl.len(): ensure indices are in the range 0..range(len(df))




Here is an approach that uses a when/then/otherwise expression to combine a forward shift and a backward shift to get one circular shift:
df.with_columns(
    b = pl.when(
        pl.col("a").shift(3).is_null()
    )
    .then(
        pl.col("a").shift(-1 * (pl.len() - 3))
    )
    .otherwise(
        pl.col("a").shift(3)
    )
)

This has the following output for your example:
shape: (9, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 8   │
│ 3   ┆ 9   │
│ 4   ┆ 1   │
│ 5   ┆ 2   │
│ 6   ┆ 3   │
│ 7   ┆ 4   │
│ 8   ┆ 5   │
│ 9   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘

(Note that at the moment the shift size in the then branch has to be written as -1 * (pl.len() - 3) instead of 3 - pl.len(), due to this issue.)
For a backwards circular shift by 3 places, you can modify the code to this,
df.with_columns(
    b = pl.when(
        pl.col("a").shift(-3).is_null()
    )
    .then(
        pl.col("a").shift(pl.len() - 3)
    )
    .otherwise(
        pl.col("a").shift(-3)
    )
)

which produces the following:
shape: (9, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
│ 4   ┆ 7   │
│ 5   ┆ 8   │
│ 6   ┆ 9   │
│ 7   ┆ 1   │
│ 8   ┆ 2   │
│ 9   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘


.append() along with slicing/head/tail could also be an option.
df.with_columns(
    b = pl.col("a").tail(3).append(pl.col("a").head(pl.len() - 3)),
    c = pl.col("a").slice(3).append(pl.col("a").head(3))
)

shape: (9, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 7   ┆ 4   │
│ 2   ┆ 8   ┆ 5   │
│ 3   ┆ 9   ┆ 6   │
│ 4   ┆ 1   ┆ 7   │
│ 5   ┆ 2   ┆ 8   │
│ 6   ┆ 3   ┆ 9   │
│ 7   ┆ 4   ┆ 1   │
│ 8   ┆ 5   ┆ 2   │
│ 9   ┆ 6   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

